# Opening Images with slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a gallery of pictures on my website.

I want to show it as a slide show(FancyBox).

The currently that picture is opening in new page and I want that the picture will move to the next picture by a click.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function loop(){
$("li:visible").click(function (){
    $(this).animate({marginLeft:"-100px", opacity:"0"}, function(){
        $(this).css({display:"none", marginLeft:"0", opacity:"1"});
        $(this).next().fadeIn(function(){
           if($("li:last").is(':visible')){
            $(this).click(function(){
    $(this).animate({marginLeft:"-100px", opacity:"0"}, function(){
        $(this).css({display:"none", marginLeft:"0", opacity:"1"});
        $("li:first").fadeIn();
    });
    });
    loop();
    }
            loop();});
    });
});
});
```

[See in live](https://jsfiddle.net/3zzj4yqr/4/)

Think, you are looking for this. Change the list with images and change the "li" in script too.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reason for this, I am listing some of these reasons:

1. You need to check position of different versions jquery file included on your page.
2. Recheck if you you have missed any jquery script on your page.